# C# inter-thread communication

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want two threads to collaborate; a producer and a consumer. 
the consumer is rather slow, and the producer is very fast and works in bursts.

for example the consumer can process one message per 20 seconds, and the producer can produce 10 messages in one second, but does it about once in a long while so the consumer can catch up.

I want something like:

```
Stream commonStream;
AutoResetEvent commonLock;

void Producer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        magic.BlockUntilMagicAvalible();
        byte[] buffer = magic.Produce();
        commonStream.Write(buffer);
        commonLock.Set();
    }
}

void Consumer()
{
    while(true)
    { 
        commonLock.WaitOne();
        MagicalObject o = binarySerializer.Deserialize(commonStream);
        DoSomething(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .Net are you using, there are some new things to v4 for exactly this stuff

Comment: .Net 3.5 ;
Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read the following articles they describe your problem. Basically you're not getting the right isolation for your unit of work.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/locking-isolation-unit-of-work-performance)
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/locking-isolation-unit-of-work-performance-solution)

Answer (score 12):

If you have .Net 4.0 or higher you can do it this way by using a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

```
int maxBufferCap = 500;
BlockingCollection<MagicalObject> Collection 
                           = new BlockingCollection<MagicalObject>(maxBufferCap);
void Producer()
{
    while (magic.HasMoreMagic)
    {
        this.Collection.Add(magic.ProduceMagic());
    }
    this.Collection.CompleteAdding();
}

void Consumer()
{
    foreach (MagicalObject magicalObject in this.Collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        DoSomthing(magicalObject);
    }
}
```

The `foreach` line will sleep if there is no data in the buffer, it will also automatically wake it self up when something is added to the collection.

The reason I set the max buffer is if your producer is much faster than the consumer you may end up consuming a lot of memory as more and more objects get put in to the collection. By setting up a max buffer size as you create the blocking collection when the buffer size is reached the `Add` call on the producer will block until a item has been removed from the collection by the consumer.

Another bonus of the `BlockingCollection` class is it can have as many producers and consumers as you want, it does not need to be a 1:1 ratio. If `DoSomthing` supports it you could have a `foreach` loop per core of the computer (or even use [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) and use the consuming enumerable as the data source)

```
void ConsumersInParalell()
{
    //This assumes the method signature of DoSomthing is one of the following:
    //    Action<MagicalObject>
    //    Action<MagicalObject, ParallelLoopState>
    //    Action<MagicalObject, ParallelLoopState, long>
    Paralell.ForEach(this.Collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(), DoSomthing);
}
```

Comment: Note that the TPL has been back-ported to .NET 3.5: http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/02/tpl-and-parallelforeach-in-net-35-using.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want using a queue and timer. The producer adds values to the queue and starts the consumer timer. The consumer timer's elapsed event (which is on a Threadpool thread) stops the timer, and loops through the queue until it's empty, then disappears (no unnecessary polling). The producer can add to the queue while the consumer is still running.

```
System.Timers.Timer consumerTimer;
Queue<byte[]> queue = new Queue<byte[]>();

void Producer()
{
    consumerTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    consumerTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(consumerTimer_Elapsed);
    while (true)
    {
        magic.BlockUntilMagicAvailable();
        lock (queue)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(magic.Produce());
            if (!consumerTimer.Enabled)
            {
                consumerTimer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}

void consumerTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        consumerTimer.Stop();
        lock (queue)
        {
            if (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                DoSomething(queue.Dequeue());
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't thread safe about it? And it doesn't poll - the timer is a one-shot that's only activated when the producer adds to the queue.

Answer (score -1):

I use Mutex's.  The idea is that both run in different threads.  The Consumer thread is started locked by a mutex, where it will sit indefinitely until release by the Producer.  It will then process data in parallel leaving the Producer to continue.  The Consumer will re-lock when complete.

(Code start the thread, and other quality bits have been omitted for brevity.)

```
// Pre-create mutex owned by Producer thread, then start Consumer thread.
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true);  
Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();

void Producer_AddData(T data)
{
  lock (queue) {
    queue.Enqueue(GetData());
  }

  // Release mutex to start thread:
  mutex.ReleaseMutex();
  mutex.WaitOne();
}

void Consumer()
{
  while(true)
  { 
    // Wait indefinitely on mutex
    mutex.WaitOne();
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

    T data;
    lock (queue) {
      data = queue.Dequeue();
    }
    DoSomething(data);
  }
```

}

This slows the Producer by a very few milliseconds whilst is waits for the Consumer to wake and release the mutex.  If you can live with that.

Comment: Using a `BlockingCollection` is much better.  First off, it's much more obvious when it's correct than using mutexes, and unlike your model the producer and the consumer can be working in parallel; you are ensuring that your code is *either* producing *or* consuming, but never both.  It also doesn't scale well to more than one producer or more than one consumer, unlike a blocking collection where doing so is trivial.  You could use a more complex mutex based approach that had the benefits of a blocking collection, but it would be a *lot* of work, and be much less readable/maintainable.

Comment: The BlockingColletion is not available to me as I cannot run 4.5.  If I could then this would probably be the correct solution.  However this code does run in parallel.  I might not have been clear, but the two are in different threads.   I use this to run heavy SQL queries on one thread, whilst gathering data on another thread and it works well for me.

Comment: BlockingCollection was added in 4.0, not 4.5.

Comment: This is partly why these solutions are problematic, it's non-trivial to reason about what's going on.  You are correct, they can run in parallel, but because you allow that it is not thread safe.  You can be removing an item from the queue at the same time that you're enqueuing a new item, which could result in all sorts of bad things happening.

Comment: I don't want to start an argument, but according to MSDN the BlockingCollection was added in 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx.  The answer I posted worked in parallel and there is nothing wrong with it for those who need this solution.  I would appreciate it if you removed your negative comment and weighting. -- You are right that I do need to LOCK {} the queue to make it thread safe.  But I stated that in my description: I wanted to show how the mechanism worked, not build a working application.

Comment: It's also worth noting that implementing your own BlockingCollection isn't too terribly hard.  If you do a lot of this kind of work in an earlier version of C# you can port it over easily enough; it's not dependent on newer language features.

Comment: No, according to MSDN [it was added in 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.100).aspx).  It's *avaliable* in 4.5, but not exclusive to 4.5.  There is not "nothing wrong with the solution".  There is a very significant race condition as a result of concurrent access in an unsafe manor to a `Queue`.

Comment: How is it without justification?  I have posted quite a few comments in which I have explained the problems with your post, and I didn't add the downvote until it seemed clear that you had no intention of fixing the problems with the post.  As to your synchronization, that's something that is *way* to important to omit in my eyes; it's way to easy to mess up.  Case in point, you didn't do it properly, you're locking on the creating of the item in the producer, thus preventing the consumer from getting an item during that processing.  This could even starve out the consumer.

Comment: Next, there's no real need for both the producer and the consumer to wait and release.  The producer can just release one every time and the consumer can just wait one every time.  It will reduce lock contention, make the code much easier to read and reason about, and has no read negative side effects.